# Which of the following is the correct behavior (g++ vs clang++-12)?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

The following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

const int& temp_func() {
    return 3;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << temp_func() << std::endl;
}
```

When compiled with g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), the result:

```
[1]    402809 segmentation fault ...
```

On the other hand, when compiled with clang++-12, the result:

```
3
```

Comment: And if you enable warnings (which you should always do, no exceptions) you will have a nice warning: `warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]` in both gcc and clang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are correct.  Your code has undefined behavior.  When you do `return 3` a temporary `int` object is created, and the reference the function returns is bound to that temporary object.  After the return statement finishes, that temporary is destroyed leaving the reference dangling.  Any access though that reference has undefined behavior.

Comment: I agree. However, the executable produced with one compiler consistently results in segmentation faults, whereas, with the other compiler, the lifetime of a temporary is extended because of a const ref. That was the reason behind my question. It's not as if the executable created using one compiler results in undefined outcomes.

Comment: @ArnabDe Most likely clang doesn't do anything in the memory location the the temporary was in, so it just access that location and 3 is still there, so that's what you get.  With gcc, it's probably marking that memory location as bad, because it is, and that causes the crash.  You've broken the language contract, so the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants, and these two different compilers are doing two different things, which is totally reasonable.

Comment: @ArnabDe - Undefined behavior doesn't mean that a compiler has to do something creative every time it builds. There's no guarantee of random outcomes... if there was, UB won't be quite so sinister. Appearing to "work" is the usual outcome.

Comment: Having a look at the asm generated by clang (https://godbolt.org/z/GerhqWhdY) and gcc (https://godbolt.org/z/Y1h43a53Y), it seems clang loads `rax` with the address of the `int 3`, then access it right after returning from the function; whereas gcc doesn't load `rax` but anyway tries to access it after returning from the function (thus forcing the segfault/UB). What I suppose clang can't ensure is that somebody has written on that stack frame before accessing `rax`.

Comment: @NathanOliver not really. gcc explicitly notices undefined behavior and moves 0 into rax, while clang actually dully copies value into stack and returns stack address. Both compilers do so only in debug mode. In release mode, gcc explicitly emits ud2, while clang does nothing with rax (resulting in garbage out).

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct behavior". This program exhibits undefined behavior by returning a dangling reference to a *temporary* which is a copy of the literal 3. As it's undefined behavior, anything can happen: The program can crash, it can silently succeed, it could display 4, or it could intermittently fail. Both behaviors you see are acceptable by the C++ standard.